# Can't get landscape value for UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey

Tags: ios, objective-c

Before iOS 8 I could use UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey to get keyboard info.

`NSValue *value = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];`

I realize that is depreciated, and as of iOS 8 it no longer works. I tried using UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey, but it seems to return the portrait value even in landscape. When I would `NSLog(@"%@", [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey]);` on iOS 7, it would log `NSRect: {{0, 0}, {162, 568}}` but when I `NSLog(@"%@", [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]);` it logs `NSRect: {{0, 0}, {568, 162}}`

Anyone know a valueForKey working on iOS 8 that would return the info in landscape mode? Or a way to "swap" the number values in [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] to make it landscape?
Thank you so so much in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keyboard_Notification_User_Info_Keys) about `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`,

> These coordinates do not take into account any rotation factors
>   applied to the window’s contents as a result of interface orientation
>   changes. Thus, you may need to convert the rectangle to window
>   coordinates (using the convertRect:fromWindow: method) or to view
>   coordinates (using the convertRect:fromView: method) before using it.

So try converting the rectangle to the view coordinates before storing it as a `CGRect` or `NSValue`, ex:

```
CGRect rect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect convertedRect = [self.view convertRect:rect fromView:nil];
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:convertedRect];
```